# Solve error this error (Must declare the scalar variable "@totalproduct".)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create proc my_procedure2
    @shopname varchar(50),
    @totalproduct varchar(225) output
as
begin
    select @totalproduct  = 'Total Product of' + @shopname + 'is' + count(p.p_id)
    from product p
    join Shop_products s on p.p_id = s.p_id
    join shop a on a.s_id = s.s_id
    where a.s_name = @shopname
end

declare @totalproduct varchar(225)

exec my_procedure2 'Kiran Electronics' ,@totalproduct = @totalproduct  output
```

This is not working at all getting error of having some scalar value.

> Must declare the scalar variable "@totalproduct".

Comment: You are trying to call a stored procedure right after deleting it?

Comment: @GSerg it was just for dropping it and updating it, i have removed that statement.

Comment: Do you execute the DECLARE and the EXEC at the same time, or do you first execute the DECLARE and then the EXEC?  Because that's how i can reproduce the error.

Comment: i first exec declare and than exec proc @Wouter

Comment: Ok that's your problem then.  The DECLARE is not persistent (unlike the create procedure).  You need the declare in the same batch as your exec.

Comment: @Wouter how can put both of them in same batch, i tried it but it failed , can u show me how it will happen?

Comment: Just highlight (select) both lines in your SSMS and hit F5.

Comment: ohh yeah it is working now, but is it necessary whenever we declare it we should execute both the statement together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a simple GO between the creation and the execution will put them in separate batches and remove the problem.

```
create proc my_procedure2
    @shopname varchar(50),
    @totalproduct varchar(225) output
as
begin
    select @totalproduct  = 'Total Product of' + @shopname + 'is' + count(p.p_id)
    from product p
    join Shop_products s on p.p_id = s.p_id
    join shop a on a.s_id = s.s_id
    where a.s_name = @shopname
end

GO

declare @totalproduct varchar(225)

exec my_procedure2 'Kiran Electronics' ,@totalproduct = @totalproduct  output
```

It works for me on SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1):

`BEGIN` and `END` aren't batch separators. When you `CREATE` a stored procedure, the **entirety** of the batch is used in the SP's definition. And by the **entirety** I mean the **entirety**; even comments before the `CREATE`.

Take something like the below:

```
--Here is a line comment

/* Here's a block comment.
This is an answer by Larnu
on the website Stackoverflow.com
Enjoy!
*/

CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc @MyParam int AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @MyParam * 10 AS YourResult;

END;

EXEC dbo.MyProc 10;

--Thank you for reading
```

Now, let's look at that Procedure's definition with `sys.sp_helptext`:

```
EXEC sys.sp_helptext N'dbo.MyProc';
```

```
text
-------------------------------------
--Here is a line comment

/* Here's a block comment.
This is an answer my larnu
on the website Stackoverflow.com
     Enjoy!
*/

CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc @MyParam int AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @MyParam * 10 AS YourResult;

END;

EXEC dbo.MyProc 10;

--Thank you for reading
```

As you can see, **everything** from the batch is in the SP's definition.

If you want to create a procedure, and then call it, you need to separate your batches. In interfaces with SQLCMD, SSMS, ADS, then that's the [`GO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver15) utility (`GO` is **not** a Transact-SQL operator). If we `DROP` that prior Procedure (`DROP PROC dbo.MyProc;`), and then put a `GO` after the `END` you get the behaviour you're after:

```
--Here is a line comment

/* Here's a block comment.
This is an answer my larnu
on the website Stackoverflow.com
     Enjoy!
*/

CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc @MyParam int AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @MyParam * 10 AS YourResult;

END;
GO
EXEC dbo.MyProc 10;

--Thank you for reading
```

Firstly, notice now when running these 2 batches you get the result `100`. Also, if you use `sys.sp_helptext`, the `EXEC` command isn't at the bottom.